# enable echo service and linux security loophole issues

Tags: security, tcp, udp, inetd

in order to enable the echo service we need to add the echo lines as the following example :

```
more /etc/inetd.conf


echo   stream  tcp     nowait  root    internal
echo   dgram   udp     wait    root    internal
```

the question is about security issues that can be regarding that echo service is enables

is there any security problem on my linux machine when we open the echo service?

If yes please explain what security problems can appears when the echo service is open?

Answer (score 6):

You don't want to enable the `dgram` (UDP) one.

That allows an attacker to make your machine send UDP packets with any content, and if attackers are able to have packets with spoofed source address delivered to you, that means any UDP packet to any destination.

For instance if the attacker does:

```
packit -t UDP -s 10.10.10.10 -S 7 -d 10.10.10.11 -D 7 -p have-fun-with-that
```

Where 10.10.10.11 is your IP address and 10.10.10.10 is the IP address of another machine in your network that also has the dgram/UDP `echo` service enabled, then that will start a continuous ping-pong between those two (note that UDP `chargen`, `time` and `daytime` (among the services built in most `inetd` implementations) have the same problem and should be avoided as well).

So by sending just *one* packet (and he can inject a few more to make matters worse), the attacker is managing have the whole bandwidth between the two victims used up, with minimal effort.

It becomes even more interesting when your start to use broadcast messages.

Even if your network will not allow spoofed packet to get to you (and they can't really do that for packets coming from the internet), others may not. So you may still be tricked into that ping-pong game with them as well (acting as victim and unwilling attacker).

Enabling the UDP `echo` service (and especially if you expose it over the internet) is a bit like willingly joining a botnet (with the botnet actions limited to have arbitrary UDP packets sent).

The fact that it allows anyone with access to your `echo` service to have you send any UDP packet anywhere also means they can do something reprehensible in your name (and for instance have your IP address banned for abuse) or possibly by-pass some firewalling mechanism.

For instance, if your machine has several interfaces (and *reverse path filtering* not enabled), for instance, one with address 10.0.0.1/24 and another one with 192.168.1.123/24, an attacker on host 10.0.0.2 could forge a [NAT-PMP packet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NAT_Port_Mapping_Protocol) with source 192.168.1.1:5351 and destination 10.0.0.1:7. And your `echo` would be sent to 192.168.1.1 and if that's a router/firewall accepting NAT-PMP, the attacker could effectively punch holes in that firewall using your machine as a proxy (and instead of a NAT-PMP packet, that could also be a SNMP PUT packet or anything else like that ping-pong starter packet evoked above).

The problem with that `echo` is that it replies with the same data as it receives. That UDP echo has been superseded by ICMP `echo` (as sent by the `ping` command) where you have different `ECHO_REQUEST` and `ECHO_REPLY` packets and those are different from UDP packets. So one cannot do much harm with a spoofed `ECHO_REQUEST` (see the [Smurf attack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smurf_attack) though).

More reading at:

- [CERT's historical advisory: UDP Port Denial-of-Service Attack](http://www.cert.org/historical/advisories/CA-1996-01.cfm)
- [GIAC: UDP Flood Denial of Service](http://www.giac.org/paper/gcih/206/udp-flood-denial-service/101057)

Comment: so if I want to summary your answer , then I can stay the state that echo service is enabled , and it will not be any damage on my system because some hacker attack

Comment: @maihabunash, I don't follow, can you please rephrase?

Comment: => StéphaneChazelas i think what he wanted to say was: "..so if i don't add the UDP-Version of echo, than everything will stay safe?!"

@maihabunash you should accept this great answer..!