# Question on scalability of echo service on Linux

Tags: rhel, xinetd, inetd

I'm trying to build a service which verifies that a network route is available.

I have used the echo service on inetd in the past and it certainly fits the purpose but i am unsure about its scaling.

Anyone ever tried to use echo for something like 50K clients? Any alternative ideas since ICMP not an option and i have a RHEL7 server to utilize?

Comment: Usually for several security reasons, namely amplification attacks, it is not advised to have the echo service active.

Comment: @Rui on UDP yes; TCP is safe enough. Georgios, see [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/170066/86440) for details.

Comment: Anything against traceroute? or monitoring directly the routes in the router via snmp?

Comment: Thanks for the replies, I've been asked to create a system that lets the client (not a pc) automaticaly know that it can access a specific network where the server resides. Maybe UDP discard is better?